# GSP: "if" doesn't work with "each"

Tags: gsp

I would like to make a rating star so I have the code below:

```
<g:each in="${1..5}" var="rateCount">
    <g:if test="rateCount < myResultList.rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

I have a rating with 4 and suppose to display 4 stars only.
However there is displaying 5 stars. So I replace the star with `${rateCount < myResultList.rating}` between the if statement and I got below items on my page:

```
true  true  true  true  false
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problems is I was missing a ${ tag, the program is working after I changed the if statement as below:

```
<g:if test="${rateCount < myResultList.rating}">
```